# How to run background task even device restarted in react native?

Tags: react-native, queue, background-task

I want to make an app that fetch data from server in background. I use react-native-queue but it's not working when device restarted. Is there any solution?

```
export default class Stores extends Component<{}> {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { nodes: [], isFetching: false, mailListener:{connecting:false},queue: null};
  }

componentDidMount(){
    this.init();
  }

async init() {
    const queue = await queueFactory();
    const present = this;

    queue.addWorker('listener', async (id, payload) => {

      //my jobs here

      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
          // Keep creating these jobs until counter reaches 3.
            queue.createJob('listener');
          resolve();
        }, 3000);
      });
    });

    queue.createJob('listener');

    queue.start();

    // Attach initialized queue to state.
    this.setState({
      queue
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like react-nativeo-threads, but nothing can stop the user from closing your app. This will also occur whenever you restart the device. There is no need to fetch stuff when app is closed, so how about you can do the fetch whenever app opens so the user always sees the up to date information?
I had similiar task in my app and here are some other advices from me:

-let the user refresh the data by himself ( I used the pull to refresh list)

-make the backend emit events and your app can listen to them, this way you dont need syncing

-the syncing task in background cannot be done on an interval smaller than 20 minutes. Your app will be rejected from appstores if you do that due to battery draining.

Good luck!